# How to get shipping method title in sales_order_save event?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, sales

How can I get shippingMethod Title in mage/sales/model/Order.php, in function _beforeSave() ?
Actually I have to set label for Shipping Description.

Comment: Hey Prashant, did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you have the order object you can get the shipping description

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); // or where ever the order is located in your observer event
echo $order->getShippingDescription();
```

Or optionally if you want all the shipping method data you should be able to retrieve it via

```
$shipping = $order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
var_dump($shipping->getData());
```

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. Its help me find out me the way. I have used `$this->getShippingDescription()`.

Comment: Be sure to close the question by either accepting the answer or deleting it so we keep the rate up

Comment: `$order->getShippingMethod()` for magento 1.5

Answer (score 1):

```
$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
$options = array();
foreach($methods as $_code => $_method)
{
    if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_code/title"))
        $_title = $_code;

    $options[] = array('value' => $_code, 'label' => $_title . " ($_code)");
}
echo "<xmp>";
print_r($options);
echo "</xmp>";
```

Comment: this is a more general solution, in case you only have the shipping method code ... ( in the order you already have the description ...)

Answer (score 1):

```
$order->getShippingDescription(); // returns Shipping Method Title
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when looking for the custom title:

```
$order         = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$shippingTitle = $order->getTracksCollection()->getFirstItem()->getTitle();
```